# php regex: find content between html tags

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I'm trying to obtain the html content between two distinct `<tags>`. Here is my current regex:

`preg_match("/<h1>(\s+)<span class=\"fn edit\">([^$]+)<\/span>(\s+)<\/h1>/", $source, $return)`

Right now it works great, unless a $ symbol is located inside the source. Obviously my regex is wrong, but I can't find the proper regex to return all the html between the two `<h1><span>` tags.

You can view my live regex here:
http://regex101.com/r/eT1fF2

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Comment: What are you trying to extract ? Post the expected output.

Comment: Use some other character than / to delimit your pattern, so you don't have to escape \/. Try # or ~. Possibly the $ is being interpreted as a variable within a "-delimited string. Try escaping it \$. You may need to use the 's' flag so that it doesn't end at an end-of-line. There are PHP libraries to parse HTML into a tree structure -- consider using them.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php or [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now it works great, unless a $ symbol is located inside the
>   source.

If you want to have $, you must not negate it as you do by using the character class `[^$]`. Instead, you can use `.` and the modifier `s` (PCRE_DOTALL), or `\C`.